# listview row content getting duplicated in android widget

Tags: android, listview, collectionview

I have a collection `view widget` i.e a `listview` to show data fetched from DB. I have implemented the `getViewAt(int position)` method in `RemoteViewsServiceFactory`. This method is getting called as per the the number returned from `getCount()`.

But the problem is the rows in the `listview` getting duplicated because the position that is passed in `getViewAt()` method is worng. Suppose if there are 6 items then sometimes the value of position if 0,0,1,2,2,3,4,3,5 sometimes 0,0,2,1,4,4,5,2,2 and so on. I am never getting the correct sequence which is 0,1,2,3,4,5.

However this does not happen when the widget is added for the first time. It only happens when I call `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged`() method to update the widget with new data.

Please suggest a way to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance. If you need more info please do let me know. Eagerly waiting for your reply.

Comment: This is an old post now. Did you find an answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the `adapter` and then populate it.
The problem will be solved

**Edit**
How to clear the custom adpater from the list and reinitialize

```
CAdpater adapter = new CAdpater(this, mylist1);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how to clear the adapter? I mean I don't have access to the instance of RemoteAdapter because it is a RemoteViewsAdapter and hence I can not directly call any method on it.

Comment: It seems the new RemoteView which is created inside getViewAt() method is not picking new date when I do the below thing

RemoteViews rowView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_row_3_3);
    rowView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_row_title, str);

It is somehow retaining old value and as a result it is showing duplicate result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had this problem and just found out what it was. I suspect others facing this problem are making the same mistake/oversight.

When I open the "MainActivity" to display a list of the database contents I was only seeing say two entries in the list. Then when I would look at the widget it would double the size of the list each time I opened the app, even though the number of entries seen from the "MainActivity" was unchanged.

Since I'd forked the original code I hadn't realised that every time I opened the "MainActivity" it was adding entries in the database and then filtering them when displaying it's own list.

So the solution is to use the same filter when querying the database from the widget.